# using an implode inside double quotes

Tags: php

why is this not valid:

`$foo = "blah blah {implode(',', $some_array['a key'])}";`

which gives the error:

> unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier

I think using a key of the array is the reason.

Is it possible to use implode inside double quotes, or do I have to put the string in a variable first?

Comment: this is pretty ugly. Why not just concatenate with `.` ?

Comment: looks just fine to me!

Comment: If it looked fine, it would work. This is just nasty looking man.

Comment: @Derek Huh? plenty of working code looks ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are using it now is designed for class propeties for instance:

```
$foo = "blah blah {$user->name}";
```

If you want to use functions without declaring the variable earlier, just use it this way:

```
$foo = 'blah blah ' . implode(',', $some_array['a key']);
```

Answer (score 4):

From the manual:

> **Complex (curly) syntax**
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax

You can't call functions inside curly brackets, and that's the reason you got that error.

You can break the string and concatenate using period:

```
$foo = "blah blah ". implode(',', $some_array['a key']). "";
                                                        # ^ This is only if you need extra string here
```